# How to add entrys in 1:1 model in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I´ve followed official documentation and much of web posts for build models and associations in sequelize.

I´ve created 2 models, user and key (passwords).
I´ve created a: `Key.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'userId'})` association.

Well, when I launch the app, `sequelize.sync()` creates tables correctly, and creates a Keys table which has these fields:

```
id (PK) // key (string) // createdAt // updatedAt // userId (FK)
```

It seems all is correct but I've been stuck for a few days here, I want to use this model in `user-controller.js` where I want create an entry in the `Users` table that automatically create an entry in Keys table but, when I do something like below, nothing happens in the `Keys` table:

```js
let newUser = await User.build({
    name: params.name,
    surname: params.surname,
    nick: params.nick,
    email: params.email,
    key: params.password            
})
    
let insertUser = await newUser.save();
```

Obviously, I'm using `brcrypt` in the original code.

If I try to trick the entry and I do something like:

```
let newIdUserEntry = insertUser.id;

let newKey = await Key.build({
    key: hashPass,
    userId: newIdUserEntry
})

newKey.save();
```

The entry in `Keys` table, has a null in `userId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really look at the [documentation page that describes inserting on `belongsTo` relations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/creating-with-associations.html).

In the first example you are simply creating a user record. In the second one, if you say the user id is null, it is probably because the value of `newIdUserEntry` was null (have you debugged that?) or maybe the field name is not matching what you declared in the model.

Anyway, I think the doc page I mentioned has exactly what you need!

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps other people, this is the code I finally implemented:

```
// Models
let User = require('../models/user')(sequelize, Sequelize);
let Key = require('../models/key')(sequelize, Sequelize);

// Associations
User.hasOne(Key, {foreignKey: 'userId'});
Key.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'userId'}); 
User.hasMany(Friend, {foreignKey: 'IDtarget'})

let newUser = await User.build({
    name: params.name,
    surname: params.surname,
    nick: params.nick.toLowerCase(),
    email: params.email.toLowerCase(),        
    Key: {
        key: hashPass
    },            
    image: null
},{
    include: [{ model: Key}]  //, through: 'userId'}]
})
```

Thanks for helping me!